# Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'

Tags: python, django

can someone tell me what is wrong with this code...

```
def format_money_value(num):
    return u'{0:.2f}'.format(num)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'
```

I'm running Django 1.5

Thank you

Comment: What is `num`? The `f` format modifier can be used only if `num` is a float. AFAIK `num` is a unicode string. You should either convert it to a float, or avoid using `f` at all.

Comment: As @Bakuriu points out, the problem is in `num`, which according to the error message is a string (of `unicode` type), and not a float.

Comment: @Bakuriu its taken from a string = 10.00

Comment: I noticed in my form its  amount = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

Comment: @Bakuriu -- It doesn't *have* to be a `float`.  It could be an `int` as well.  I'm not actually sure what the concrete requirement is ...

Comment: @Bakuriu `format`accepts any `numerical type` that can be represented as `float`. You can use `int` or `Decimal` with `format` too.

Comment: thank you, it was a string @Bakuriu you really helped me understand thank you

Comment: What I meant is that you can use `f` *iff* `float(num)` returns a float.

Comment: As a side note, @Bakuriu -- You should post your comment as an answer.  I'm pretty sure that is the cause of OP's problem and It's better to have questions answered I think.

Comment: @Bakuriu -- No.  `float('10.0')` will return a `float`, but OP's code doesn't work if you use `num = '10.0'` (which was a surprise to me)

Comment: @mgilson Oh, yes... obviously. Then I believe the requirement is "the object has a `__float__` method...

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Yes, that's probably it.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't make any attempt to call `__float__`.  What it actually does is call the object's `__format__` method.

Answer (score 22):

In your case `num` is a unicode string, which does not support the `f` format modifier:

```
>>> '{0:.2f}'.format(u"5.0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'
```

You can fix the error making the conversion to `float` yourself:

```
>>> '{0:.2f}'.format(float(u"5.0"))
'5.00'
```

---

As pointed out by mgilson when you do `'{0:.2f}'.format(num)`, the `format` method of the strings calls `num.__format__(".2f")`. This results in an error for `str` or `unicode`, because they don't know how to handle this format specifier. Note that the meaning of `f` is left as an implementation for the object. For numeric types it means to convert the number to a floating point string representation, but other objects may have different conventions.

If you used the `%` formatting operator the behaviour is different, because in that case `%f` calls `__float__` directly to obtain a floating point representation of the object.
Which means that when using `%`-style formatting `f` *does* have a specific meaning, which is to convert to a floating point string representation.

Comment: Actually, I think that the magic is done in the object's `__format__` method.  e.g. `'{0:.2f}'.format(num)` calls `num.__format__('.2f')` and replaces the braketed text with the return value.

Comment: @mgilson Yes, that must be it. The `%`-style formatting calls `__float__` while `.format` simply calls `__format__`. Anyway I must say that the error messages that you get are quite confusing...

Comment: My only explanation for these is that random drive-by downvoting happens sometimes.  Stack Overflow needs to put more strict regulations on what users they allow to have mouse privileges.  (e.g., they should do background checks before allowing users to click)

Comment: @mgilson I'm puzzled because 20 minutes before I got also a downvote in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917814/expand-certain-substrings-elegantly-inside-a-larger-string-in-python/15917861#15917861) answer, which I belive doesn't deserve it...

Comment: Upvoted to eliminate *un-commented down vote* .Sometimes, users wish to check other answers of the answerer. But down voting without defining the reason is pointless since it supply no clue about the problem of the answer.

Comment: If `5.0` provided as string variable how can I covert its type into `u`

Answer (score 5):

### what .format() do

`str.format` method calls  `__format__()` method of related type. That means

```
<type>.__format__(<value>, <spec>)
```

above method accepts the same type argument as first value, and accepts a suitable `spec` type
 as second one. Like,

```
str.__format__('1', 's')
int.__format__(1, 'f')
float.__format__(1.00, 'f')
```

`str.__format__` accepts any type that is derived from `str` type, like `str` or `unicode`. Spec value must be a valid formatter that is usable of that type. Following will raise an error

```
str.__format__('1', 'f')
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

since `floating point` formatting is not a *suitable* format type fot string. Likewise following will raise an error too

```
float.__format__(1.00, 's')
ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'float'
```

since float is a `numeric` type and can not formatted as a `string`. But following are all valid:

```
float.__format__(1.00, 'g')
float.__format__(1.00, 'f')
```

similarly following will raise an exception

```
float.__format__(1.00, 'd')
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'
```

since formatting a float point to a decimal value will cause precision values to be lost. But formatting an `int` to `float` will not cause a such thing, so it is a valid conversion:

```
int.__format__(1, 'f')
```

So `.format()` is limeted to `specs` that is available to the related formatting `type`. You must parse your value as @Bakuriu defined:

```
'{0:.2f}'.format(float(u"5.0"))
```

Comment: the old formatting [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) seem to have behaved differently. `"%s"(anything,)` formats `anything` with (a compatible) `__str__` attribute to string, right? can you do that with the 2.6+ format syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The scenario where you are re-formatting a string (unicode or otherwise) as a float string is not very safe. You should first convert the string to a numeric representation and only if that succeeds should you format it as a string again. You are not in control of the data that comes into your program so you should be sure to validate it coming in.

If you choose to leave it as a string you can use this:

```
return u"{:.2f}".format(num) if num.isnumeric() else u"{}".format(num)
```

If you have already converted the string into a numeric format, you can adjust your formatter like this:

```
return u"{:.2f}".format(num) if isinstance(num, NumberTypes) else u"{}".format(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem as the OP, when `num` was a numerical answer returned by one of my libraries, whose implementation detais got forgotten:

```
>>> num
-4132.56528214700
>>> u'{0:.4g}'.format(num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'unicode'
```

I was really puzzled because `num` *behaved* like a float but after testing @Bakuriu 's solution, I've found out it wasn't a float:

```
>>> type(num)
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
```

So @Bakuriu 's solution was right on target for my case:

```
>>> u'{0:.4g}'.format(float(num))
u'-4133'
```

Therefore, the error can be due to types that display/calculate like but aren't really floats.