# django1.8- concatenate fields in Excel and upload in database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

The read data from excel and insert into sqlite database.

The excel has two columns : "Year" and "Month". When inserting into database, I want to concatenate like below: "2013-12-31",the default date is always 31.

Here below is the snippet and reports error that "global name 'Concat' is not defined":

**views.py**

```
curs = connection.cursor()
query = """Insert into xxxx(year, month, date,...) values (%s,%s,,,,)"""
for row in range(0,sheet.nrows):
    values=[]
    global year_var
    global month_var

    for col in range(0, sheet.ncols):
        if col==0:
                year_var = sheet.cell(row, col).value
            if col==1:
                month_var = sheet.cell(row,col).value
                date= Concat(year_var,'-',month_var,'-','01')   <!--here is wrong-->
            if col==3:
                values.append(date)

            var = sheet.cell(row, col).value
            values.append(var)
        curs.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: Please fix indentation of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> year_var = 2015
>>> month_var = 12
>>> '{}-{}-{}'.format(year_var, month_var, '01')
'2015-12-01'
```

or [`%`-operator (printf-style formatting)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
>>> '%s-%s-%s' % (year_var, month_var, '01')
'2015-12-01'
```

**UPDATE** According to OP's comment

The values could be passed as float values: `2015.0`, `3.0`

```
>>> year_var = 2015.0
>>> month_var = 3.0
>>> '{:04.0f}-{:02.0f}-{}'.format(year_var, month_var, '01')
'2015-03-01'

>>> '%.0f-%02.0f-%s' % (year_var, month_var, '01')
'2015-03-01'
```

Comment: ,hi I just realized an issue: even though the date in excel is "2011", and "03" for year and month. But after concatenating using your 2 methods and inserting into database, it will become "2010.0-3.0-01". There is a ".0" added automatically. How can I remove it? In the model, both year and month are defined as "charfield". thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Héléna, Thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: it reports an error of "Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'". I see on the following post, saying that f format modifier is only used for float. But my case is that both fields are defined as "Charfield". Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924879/unknown-format-code-f-for-object-of-type-unicode